# How to console log elements with upper case in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, uppercase

I am trying to log to the console the upper case element however, the console throws this error each time: TypeError: arrayNames[i].toUpperCase is not a function

```js
var hello = "Hello, ";
var arrayNames = [];

function greet(name) {

  if (name == null) {
console.log(hello + "my friend");
  }

  //Requirement UpperCase
  arrayNames.push(name);
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayNames.length; i++) {
if (arrayNames[i] === arrayNames[i].toUpperCase()) {
  console.log(hello.toUpperCase() + arrayNames[i].toUpperCase());
}
  }
  //Requirement last element

  if (arrayNames.length > 1) {
var lastElement = arrayNames.pop();
console.log(hello + arrayNames + " and " + lastElement);
  }
  else {
console.log(hello + arrayNames);
  }

}

greet(["James", "Julie", "BEN"]);
```

Comment: Because `name` should be a string but when you are calling the function `greet`, you are passing an array.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @nikhil

Answer (score 1):

You are using toUpperCase on an array.
The problem is the line:

```
arrayNames.push(name);
```

You are creating a multidimensional Array.
Use

```
arrayNames = name;
```

instead.

Comment: I'd rather suggest using `.concat`

Answer (score 1):

You are creating array of array by this

`arrayNames.push(name)`

Instead do this

`arrayNames = name`

Which will simply refer to the same array `name`.

`toUpperCase()` function can only be called on a string and not an array.

See modified code bellow:

```js
var hello = "Hello, ";
var arrayNames = [];

function greet(name){
  if(name==null){
    console.log(hello + "my friend")
  }
  //Requirement UpperCase
  arrayNames = name; // NOTICE THE CHANGE HERE
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayNames.length; i++) {
    if(arrayNames[i]===arrayNames[i].toUpperCase()){
        console.log(hello.toUpperCase() + arrayNames[i].toUpperCase());
    }
  }
  //Requirement last element
  if(arrayNames.length>1){
    var lastElement = arrayNames.pop();
    console.log(hello + arrayNames + " and " + lastElement);
  }else{
    console.log(hello + arrayNames)
  }
}

greet(["James", "Julie", "BEN"]);
```

Comment: Excellent thank you. Is there a way i can use the greet function with an array and without? For example greet("James") would return "Hello, James" and greet(["James", "Julie", "BEN"]) would return arrays of names

Comment: `arrayNames = name` won't create another copy of the array. It will just refer the one which was passed. So, inside function `name` and `arrayNames` are same.

Comment: @EyedFox1 You can do that by using `typeof name` it'll return `object` if it is an array and `string` if argument passed is a string.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code, you have push the name of arrays in another array.

Replace this line "arrayNames.push(name)" with "arrayNames = name;"